# VBA: How to find the first unhidden row

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following to find the last unhidden row:

```
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

How would I do the same for the first unhidden row?

EDIT: I'd like to find the first unhidden row excluding A1.

Comment: @BigBen you are correct. fascinating.

Comment: Do you mean the first *populated* unhidden row? EDIT: seems not.

Comment: @BigBen - I tried this but doesn't seem to work. Also edited the question - I do not want to count A1. I want this variable to point to the first unhidden row starting from A2.

Comment: But ultimately I wonder what you are trying to do with the first and last?  If you are trying to set a range then just set the range to the extremes of the data and use specialcells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
```

Get the `Row` of the first visible cell in Column A (a.k.a. Column 1), regardless of whether or not it contains any data

---

Since the question has been modified to request that Row 1 be excluded from the test, here's a version for that:

```vb
Dim rTestRange AS Range, lRow AS Long
Set rTestRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1), _ 'Start from Row 2
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,1)) 'Until the bottom row of the sheet
lRow = rTestRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row 'First visible row
```